# SUM query, between dates, grouped by employee

Tags: sql-server-2012, sum, aggregate

I have 4 tables, structured as follows:

[image: Database Diagram]

More verbosely, a *project* consists of a set of *tasks*.  An *employee* can add one or more *notes* to the database, specifying the *amount of time* spent on that *task* on any given *date*.

I would like to find for each employee, how long he's worked on a given task in total, between two dates.  My first stab at this was as follows:

```
SELECT  Project.Name AS ProjectName,
        Task.Name AS TaskName,
        Employee.Name AS EmployeeName,
        SUM(Note.WorkDuration)
        FROM 
        Note 
        INNER JOIN
        Employee 
        ON
        Note.ID_Employee = Employee.ID
        INNER JOIN
        Task
        ON
        Task.ID = Note.ID_Task
        INNER JOIN
        Project
        ON
        Task.ID_Project = Project.ID
        WHERE 
        Note.WorkDate BETWEEN '01/05/2015' AND '08/05/2015'
        GROUP BY
        Task.Name, Project.Name, Employee.Name
        ORDER BY
        Employee.Name
        ASC
```

However this given the wrong value with a populated database.  Can anyone help me understand how to do this?

The idea is to somehow make this query write into an Excel table, with projects/tasks along Y and employee name along X, with each cell containing the total time worked on the task.

Update:  If I change the BETWEEN clause to:

```
Note.[Date] BETWEEN '20150501' AND '20150508'
```

It seems to work correctly.  So I have a date format issue.

Comment: Are your dates inclusive or exclusive?

Comment: Dates are inclusive.

Comment: Can you paste in some anonymised data into the question. Your query looks ok.

Comment: So I started doing this for you and saw when I was selecting records that the WHERE - BETWEEN clause isn't working correctly.  I set the dates as above and I'm getting records from March in there too.  Have I done something wrong with the date format such that it's being converted somehow?

Comment: Field [Date] is DateTime2 btw.

Comment: Whenever you are using hard coded dates, Use ANSI Date format: 'yyyy-MM-dd'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"So I started doing this for you and saw when I was selecting records that the WHERE - BETWEEN clause isn't working correctly. I set the dates as above and I'm getting records from March in there too. Have I done something wrong with the date format such that it's being converted somehow? –  Robinson 18 mins ago"

It depends on where you're from and what your default settings are for date format; I would guess that you're NOT from the US (since you seem to put the day before the month in '01/05/2015'), but I bet your server's format is set to US standards (month/day/year).  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx

The safest thing to do is to use a universal standard like you did in your second try: yyyymmdd  (or even better: yyyy-mm-dd).

Comment: I would add [this link to MSDN/](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx) to your answer. +1

Comment: Great.  It works now.  Thank you Stuart and Nattrass for poking me in the right direction.